# Register/Login user using their Google Account?

Tags: android, oauth-2.0

I want my users to login with their Google accounts.

SwiftKey and Catch Notes do it by opening a WebView in their apps. I don't want to do that. I want to use AccountManager.

Tasks Free from Team Tasks uses it and loads your Google tasks easily. The official Google Reader app also uses it and loads your Google Reader feeds.

But I don't want to get any data of the user from Google except their name, email, etc. I only want to register the user and log them back in easily.

How do I register them with OAuth tokens etc?

All the examples I have found either use WebView or only load data from Google (not register).

Comment: This could be helpful: http://android-developers.blogspot.com.es/2013/01/verifying-back-end-calls-from-android.html?m=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I first asked this question, it was really really hard to do. You had to use the Google Java API definitely not built for Android.

But there is now Google Play Services and this task is very easy to do.

Anyone can follow the below links:

https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/sign-in

https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Google I/O 2011 covered Android + App Engine, which uses Google accounts for authentication. The Android client uses AccountManager. Here's the [screenshot](http://bradabrams.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/image031.jpg).

You may want to look at [AccountsActivity](http://code.google.com/p/cloud-tasks-io/source/browse/trunk/CloudTasks-Android/src/com/cloudtasks/AccountsActivity.java) in the source code.

Comment: I have used lots of things from the source code of Google I/O 2011. I didn't realize what I need is actually is in it. Google I/O apps are really full of resources. Thank you.

Comment: OK. I have looked at the code you have given. After he get the authToken, it sends it to the Google AppEngine and get the Cookie from it. The server at the AppEngine should be doing some stuff to authenticate the user based only on the authToken given. How can it do that?